# How to fix "ENOENT: no such file or directory" when downloading artifact from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I'm trying to run automated tests with AppCenter. For this, I need to get the apk from Jenkins and the ipa from another Jenkins in a TFS Build to send them to AppCenter. I'm using the "Jenkins Download Artifact" task in TFS. For the apk, everything works fine.
But for the ipa, TFS see all the artifact from the last build, select the one that match the name pattern but whenever the download begin, the build fail and throw instantly a Error

> [error]Unhandled: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Agt1_work\308\s\jenkinsArtifacts\delivery\APPNAME-calabash-5.22-build-1557912880-date-20190515-11:34:40.ipa'

The login used has all right on the Jenkins, and if I go manually on the Jenkins the download is working.

On the Jenkins on the url I can manually download artifacts

> http://IPADDRESS:8080/job/JOBNAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/delivery/

Is the TFS task, the Job Name is the Job Name in the url
the rest of the task configuration :
[image]

And the Endpoint configuration :
[image]

It shouldn't matter but note that the Jenkins is on a computer in a internal network so I use the IP address in the url.

with this configuration when I build (with System.Debug at true) I have this Error
[image]

I don't have a direct access to the computer where the jenkins is. So I don't know the exact configuration of the jenkins.

Comment: i don't think 'APPNAME-calabash-5.22-build-1557912880-date-20190515-11:34:40.ipa' is a valid filename because of the ':'